# Null API Responses and HTTP 200

Tags: javascript, json, fetch

I'm working with toggl API.
In the documentation it says:

> Successful request will return 200 OK. If the user has no access to
> delete, you'll get a status code 4xx

//Request

```
fetch('https://api.track.toggl.com/api/v8/clients/1239455', {
    method: 'DELETE'
}).then(function (response) {
    if(response.ok){
        return JSON.parse(response);
    }
    return Promise.reject(response);
}).then(function (data) {
    console.log(data);
}).catch(function (error) {
    console.warn('Something went wrong.', error);
});
```

When running other methods I always convert the string to JSON.
Here the API returns null upon successful execution.
So how can I read the response from the server?

Comment: You can check the response.status

Comment: But ```response``` is a string?

Comment: If so, how can you check for the response.ok?

Comment: If the function returns ```null``` is there anything I could do with that?